# buying bitcoin with Amazon gift card

Tags: buy-bitcoins

why all the sellers whom selling bitcoin with Amazon gift card are asking for physical cards with a receipt for it.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's no current way to check the Amazon gift card balance without actually depositing the gift card into your account.

See [this post](https://blog.purse.io/bitcoin-powers-huge-discounts/) from purse.io for more details.

Answer (score 1):

well because there are a lot of scams out there especially on amazon. Most sellers requires that the amazon gift card is purchased with cash and they need receipt because a lot of scammers and hackers are stealing peoples credit card information and buying these gift cards online and using those gift cards to buy bitcoins, now once the credit card holder notice the charge on their cards they dispute it and if the seller of the bitcoin haven't use the card balance than it will be removed from the card. The sellers are being careful because it would be their lost. I have a $25 amazon gift card that I bought from walgreens to buy bitcoins and because I misplaced the receipt I can't buy the bitcoin.